# Event which fires right after items creation in NestedList

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

Is there in event in **Sencha Touch 2** for **NestedList** which is fired when the list items are builded (**DOM is ready**)?

Comment: what do you mean by **list items are builded**

Comment: @sai, that means when DOM is ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `activate` which Fires whenever item within the Container is activated.

or

`show` which Fires whenever the Component is shown

or

if you want an event after records are loaded then use `load` which Fires whenever records have been loaded into the store

Comment: As I understand `show` event is not firing on sub element. It fires only on first level elements (Views). `load` event is firing even if DOM of items is not ready. :(

Answer (score 1):

Go through events like load, painted, beforeload, show, initialize in http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList , you'll find one which will suit you.
If you are looking for something else please elaborate.

Comment: I've tested all those events before asking the question, but there is still possibility that event will be fired before DOM is ready... That's the problem. :(